# Storing generated accounts. Security

Tags: go-ethereum, security, web3j

I originally built a system that had a front end where users simply entered some details and a password which then generated them a wallet and emailed it to them. My aim was that the user could then choose whether to run their own node or use the web interface to send transactions(form with a file picker to select the wallet and a password field).

I'm unsure as to the best approach to take here, is it more secure to keep the wallet files server side, and just ask users to enter their wallet password to send transactions, or allow them to keep their own wallet and upload it to a temp folder each time they want to transact using the server's node?

It's a 'private' blockchain btw. With probably minimal chance of an attacker wanting to compromise the server.

I know ideally it would be best to provide a client UI and ask all users to use their own node so wallets and passwords could be kept away from the server but this is a greater technical requirement for the users than I would like.

Comment: Why do you even need a blockchain ?! you can sign messages using their username or password or anything you want.

Comment: We are collecting data that we would like to be secure and immutable, this is also a research project so we are experimenting with blockchain. Yes we have a central server to serve the web application however the blockchain aspect is still decentralised. Signatures have been implemented, a smart contract does not accept data unless an address it generates from Ecrecover matches a list of valid addresses @MickySocaci